# ClickOnce application installation failing when installing from network share

Tags: winforms, clickonce, installation, network-share

When I copy installation files to local folder and run setup from there - everything works fine, but when I try to run setup from a network share I get this type of error:

**Error information below:**

```
LATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows: 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.18444
System.Deployment.dll: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
clr.dll: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
dfdll.dll: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
dfshim.dll: 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES    
Deployment url: file:///C:/(path../AppName).application
Deployment Provider url: file://(server/path/AppName).application

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:/(path../AppName).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:

+ Downloading file://(server/path/AppName).application did not succeed.

+ The network name cannot be found.

+ The network name cannot be found.

+ The network name cannot be found.


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [22-07-2014 08:37:35] : Activation of C:/(path../AppName).application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [22-07-2014 08:37:35] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
- Downloading file://(server/path/AppName).application did not succeed.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
    at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
    at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)


--- Inner Exception ---
System.Net.WebException
- The network name cannot be found.

- Source: System
- Stack trace:
    at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
    at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

--- Inner Exception ---
System.Net.WebException
- The network name cannot be found.

- Source: System
- Stack trace:
    at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
    at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)

--- Inner Exception ---
System.IO.IOException
- The network name cannot be found.

- Source: mscorlib
- Stack trace:
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
    at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
    at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

(..)

Why is this happening and what could I do to make it possible to install ClickOnce application from network share (I can not use web address for this)?

I need multiple user to have access to this installation and making each one of them download installation before installing doesn't sound user friendly way.

P.S. I have found a lot of questions about this type of a problem, but I can't find an answer that would help me...

Comment: Removing the most important parts of this error message isn't very helpful... Please add the full error message and just obfuscate things like server names, applications names, user names or passwords.

Comment: @Herdo Hi, added full error text to the post

Comment: Thanks. "The network name cannot be found." Looks like a typo in the deployment settings of ClickOnce. Please check that the client has access to the provided `Installation Folder URL` defined on the publishing page.

Comment: This might also be a permission issue. The .NET framework can't run certain things from a network share due to code security settings.

Comment: @Matt maybe you can share some good resource with information about what .NET framework can not run from a network share because code security settings?

Comment: @Matt it seems that You were right - if You would post an aswer with some additional information maybe, I will accept it! Thanks all for the help!

Comment: @Prokurors did you all end up having to use CasPol.exe to FullTrust the network share? Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: @Matt actually I don't have a solution... users just have to copy installation to their desktops before installing, and that ofcourse is a bit of a problem :( But I read also somewhere else that these type of problems most likely is permission issues. But this caspol.exe - it's something that has to be executed on each user machine? Does this not require elavated rights?

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you makes some mistakes while deploy the application: please note that you have selected Download prerequisties from the  **component wender's website**, as mentioned in the picture, at that point select **Download prerequisties from the same location as my application** then press ok to continue.[image: picture]

for more clarification and deployment guidelines https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3234

Comment: He's not even using the bootstraper. Why should the prerequisites be the problem?

Comment: when you select **Download prerequisties from the component wender's website** @ this point then it need to download the .net Frame work,mysql/sql server and other supported software from the internet @ the time of installation, **Download prerequisties from the same location as my application** will help you to attach these essentials from the local machine its self.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil well In my case users don't have elevated user rights - they will not have rights to install anything (that's not ClickOnce App) And if they install application from local folder, installation is successful, so it's not about missing prerequisites